# C# Write from text file to listView

Tags: c#

I created windows application in C# that writes from text file to listView.
I first executed commands in cmd to list system and user apps from the phone and I put cmd output to text file.
Now I want to add content of text file to listView: in first column apps from /system/app should be listed, in second apps from /system/priv-app and in third apps from /data/app!
When I press the button to execute function I get error:System.ArgumentException: Cannot add or insert the item '' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.

```
Process  process;
ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process = new Process();
    startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C adb devices&adb shell pm list packages -f";
}

private void Redirect_ADB_Output()
{
    using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText("ADB.txt", result);
        }
    }   
}

private void WriteToListView()
{
    ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
    var lines = File.ReadLines("ADB.txt");
    foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
            if (line != string.Empty)
            {
                var newLine = line.Remove(0, 8);

                if (line.Contains("package:/system/app"))
                {
                    ApkList.Items.Add(newLine);
                }
                if (line.Contains("package:/system/priv-app"))
                {
                    lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
                }
                if (line.Contains("package:/data/app"))
                {
                    lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
                }
            }
            ApkList.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }
    File.WriteAllText("ADB.txt", string.Empty);
}

private void btn_PullApkFromPhone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C adb devices&adb shell pm list packages -f";
    Redirect_ADB_Output();

    WriteToListView();
}
```

Comment: I think that you should create the `lvItem` every time you are going to add it to the `ApkList` items. i.e., inside de `for`.

Comment: Now there is no error but I have this problem: https://postimg.org/image/3z10vsawqz/

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because you are modifying an element while looping over it.

Try creating a new object and adding that to the collections (also, as another user pointed out, try moving the ListView into the foreach loop):

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();

    var newLine = line.Remove(0, 8);

    if (line.StartsWith("package:/system/app"))
    {
        ApkList.Items.Add(newLine);
    }
    if (line.StartsWith("package:/system/priv-app"))
    {
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
    }
    if (line.StartsWith("package:/data/app"))
    {
        lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
    }
    ApkList.Items.Add(lvItem);
}
```

Comment: Now I have this error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count

Comment: I used start index and count .Remove(int startIndex, int count)

Comment: Why do I get error?This error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count is not caused by . in .Remove method

Comment: Empty lines in the text file?

Comment: Yes there are empty lines!

Comment: Try using ".contains()" instead of StartsWith?  Also I am not helping someone that yells and throws a fit that his/her code isn't working.  I think you need to take step back and maybe reword what you say here or think about your code more before you come at us yelling and demanding to know why something YOU wrote doesn't work.  Period.  You will not get far at SO with that attitude.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.  When you calm down, you should post the stack error with the line # that is throwing it.

Comment: It's throwing exception because of empty lines

Comment: I updated code in question.I added if (line != string.Empty) then remove from string

Comment: Why it doesn't list correctly and why it doesn't show anything below /data/app column?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first adding "columns", this helps.

```
ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem();
ApkList.View = View.Details;
ApkList.Columns.Add("Col1");
ApkList.Columns.Add("Col2");
ApkList.Columns.Add("Col3");
```

THEN You need to do this for the foreach.

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
  if (line != string.Empty)
  {
      var newLine = line.Remove(0, 8);

      if (line.Contains("package:/system/app"))
      {
          lvItem.Text = newLine;
      }
      if (line.Contains("package:/system/priv-app"))
      {
          lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
      }
      if (line.Contains("package:/data/app"))
      {
          lvItem.SubItems.Add(newLine);
      }
   }            
}

ApkList.Items.Add(lvItem);
```

You'll then need a final loop around the above, for, foreach, while to populate your entire list.

Comment: Google is your friend.  There is tons of info on how to properly populate a listView.